# Como puedo coger los datos de los campos, al seleccionar el boton

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objeto

Como puedo coger los datos de los campos, al seleccionar el boton, en js, quiero coger, los campos span, como puedo hacerlo, con el DOM de js

```
´<div class="card" name="item1">
 <img class="img_pk" src="https://unpkg.com/pokeapi- 
  sprites@2.0.2/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/1.svg" alt="">
  <div>
  <span>Bulbasaur</span> -
   <span class="attack">49</span> Attack
  </div>
  <button id="seleccionado">Seleccionar</button>
  </div> ´
```

Comment: Se puede hacer de muchas formas. ¿cual has probado tu y que error te ha dado? ¿donde te has encallado? Y aclara cual es el resultado esperado, pues no se entiende que valores quieres realmente, si los contenidos en los span o los contenidos en todo el div que contiene los span.

Comment: var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); yo he hecho eso, pero no se como acceder a la informacion

Comment: Quieres agarrar el valor 49 del span cuando le das al boton?